# geom_image(): how to set image sizes individually

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

This question is related to [Can geom_image() from the ggimage package be made to preserve the image aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479779/can-geom-image-from-the-ggimage-package-be-made-to-preserve-the-image-aspect-r) but in my application I want to make a scatterplot, using images scaled in proportion to their **actual** image sizes.

The figure (done manually, with PPT) I want to reproduce with `geom_image()` is shown here:

[image]

I read the data as follows, and get the image sizes using `readPNG()` in the `png` package:

```
> brains.dat <- file.path(folder, "brain-size.csv")
> brains <- read.csv(brains.dat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> brains$class <- factor(brains$class)
> 
> library(png)
> 
> sizes <- t(sapply(brains$img, function(x) dim(readPNG(x))))
> brains$height <- sizes[,1]
> brains$width  <- sizes[,2]
> brains
                species       class brain_weight neurons          img height width
1              Capybara non-primate         48.2    0.30 capybara.png     31    70
2        Rhesus Macaque     primate         69.9    1.71   rhesus.png     63    75
3       Western Gorilla     primate        377.0    9.10  gorilla.png     71    95
4                 Human     primate       1232.0   16.30    human.png     98   117
5 African Bush Elephant non-primate       2848.0    5.59 elephant.png     98   168
>
```

I don't see any way to set the height and width of each image in the call below to `geom_image()`:

```
library(ggimage)
library(ggplot2)
col <- ifelse(brains$class=="primate", "blue", "red")
ggplot(brains, aes(x=brain_weight, y=neurons)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=species), color=col, hjust="inward") +
    geom_image(aes(image=img)) + theme_bw()
```

What I get from this makes all images about the same size, in width I think.  I'm ignoring the tweaks needed to position the labels better.

[image]

**Edit**: This was filed as an issue, https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/ggimage/issues/6.  The author says this is not yet supported, but perhaps there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

supported as example showed on https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/ggimage/issues/6.